# KeyError when I want to increase object and put him to dict

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, key

I would like to iterate over whole `data` list and create dict with increase value, where key will be `userId`. I have `userId` and I add 1 in the loop, but I recived an error: `KeyError: 100`

```
todos = {}

data = [
  {
    "userId": 100,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": True
  },
  {
    "userId": 200,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": True
  },
  {
    "userId": 300,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": True
  }
]

for i in data:
  todos[i['userId']] += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss to insert the element if not present in "todos" dictionary, I changed your code like this:

```
todos = {}    
data = [
  {
    "userId": 100,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": True
  },
  {
    "userId": 200,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": True
  },
  {
    "userId": 300,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": True
  }
]

for i in data:
  if i['userid'] in todos: # if key data exist in the dict, it update the value
      todos[i['userId']] += 1 
  else
     todos[i['userid']]=1 ## otherweise it create a new item with value set to 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`collections.Counter`**:

```
print(Counter(x['userId'] for x in data))
# Counter({100: 1, 200: 1, 300: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary todos is empty, you are trying to find the value in todos with key 100 (i['userId']) but it does not exist. You need to first add the entry to the dictionary before trying to add one to it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- `i['userId']` will return the value, which is `100` for your first dict.
- `todos` is an empty dict so you won't have any key in it.

I'm not sure what you want to do (count the number of dictionaries ? Sum the `userId` ?), I take it you want to get the sum of `userId` here.

I suggest you use a `defaultdict` if you're not sure what is going to be inside your dictionary (but still know that its values will be integers):

```
from collections import defaultdict

todos = defaultdict(int)

data = [
  {
    "userId": 100,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": True
  },
  {
    "userId": 200,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": True
  },
  {
    "userId": 300,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": True
  }
]

for i in data:
  todos['userId'] += i['userId']
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve on the answer of @jc1850:
To get around this you could change your code to check if the key exists:

```
for i in data
    userid = i['userId']
    if userid not in todos: todos[userid] = 0
    todos[i['userId']] += 1
```

Alternatively you can use `collections.defaultdict`. For int type, if a key doesn't exist it assumes that the value is 0:

```
from collections import defaultdict

todos = defaultdict(int)
for i in data
    todos[i['userId']] += 1
```